# ScriptLogic Information

Tags: networking

Does anyone know where ScriptLogic stores all the user information?

For the product Desktop Authority!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user information or profile is written to the netlogon share and replicated to the DC's in order to process their logon and provide fault tolerance.  The information about machines and software on the network is saved in a SQL database.

Comment: Thanks a lot! do you know the default name of the database where the information is stored.

Comment: If you allowed Desktop Authority to install SQL Server for you (it would be an instance of SQL Express), it will be in an instance called DESKTOPAUTHORITY. Otherwise, whatever instance of SQL you installed to, the default database names (there are two) is "DAConfiguration", where your configuration information is stored and "DAReporting" where reporting information is stored.